# Strengtheing a weak bed frame

Tags: framing

I bought a 200x90 cm. bed and assembled it. The bed frame is assembled out of hollow iron rods. After using for a few days I started having back pain. So I checked the bed and found that some of those rods got bent in the middle and that made the whole frame uneven. I want to strengthen it, however I don't have much stuff at hand, and we are in a lockdown due to coronavirus.

I have not thrown out the wooden planks from my older bed. So I thought putting them on the bars will distribute the load and may help it. My question is what is the pattern that will provide maximum strength? I arranged them in a way (see picture) and it already feels quite solid. I will appreciate any feedback. For information, I don't have an electronic drill machine or any such thing; also I don't know how to use them.

Thank you for reading, it is my first post here. :)
[image]

Comment: If the frame is that weak and janky that it bends under normal use, send it back for a refund.  At least email the supplier so that you have a dated record of notifying them.

Comment: Disassembling will take too much time, I am really novice in setting up things. Also, the packaging was very compact when it arrived. I have notified the supplier anyway. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That actually looks pretty well supported the way you did it. If you haven't straightened the rods that bent, you should try to do so. Also, if you have any duct tape, put a strip of it on each end and one down the middle to help hold those planks in place. Good luck and stay safe.

Comment: Thank you! I have straightened the rods as much as I can. The duct tape idea is interesting! As the mattress fits a bit tightly with the bed frame—it does not jump or shift when I sit—they are not moving, but duct tape will be a long term solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Key here appears keeping the ends in place. Ordinarily I'd recommend a beam of wood to straighten them on, but with a roll of duct-tape you can make something that will last you the crisis easily.